# Custom System Tray for a Custom Shell

Tags: shell, winapi, system-tray

I'm creating a custom shell for Windows 7 / 8. How do I create a custom tray for my shell ? I'm aware that the tray window has the class name "Shell_TrayWnd". I tried creating it on my own and posted "TaskbarCreated" message using PostMessage but I'm not getting "WM_COPYDATA" message in my Tray WndProc. I'm missing out on something? Need help.

The code is as follows:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK tray_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
   if (uMsg == WM_COPYDATA)
   {
        COPYDATASTRUCT *cpdata = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)lParam;
   }
   return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int init_tray(void) 
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = tray_proc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("Shell_TrayWnd");

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

tray_window = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
    wc.lpszClassName,
    NULL,
    WS_POPUP,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    NULL, NULL,
    wc.hInstance,
    NULL);

if (!tray_window)
    return 0;

/* let running apps know that a new tray is around */
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("TaskbarCreated")), 0, 0);

return 1;
}
```

Comment: How is broadcasting a `"TaskbarCreated"` message related to `WM_COPYDATA`? Maybe your customer liaison should get back with the client and provide you with the real, unabridged question. As posted, it doesn't compile to make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I have seen in another shell ,that "TaskbarCreated" message was broadcasted after creating the tray window. If it doesn't make sense, do you mind helping me out? My objective is to get a custom tray.

Comment: I'd start by using the correct terminology. It's never been known as the tray. It's the notification area.

Comment: @IInspectable: the `"TaskbarCreated"` message lets apps know that the taskbar is available, including its notification area. Some apps wait for that message before calling (or re-calling) `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, which in turn sends `WM_COPYDATA` messages to the `Shell_TrayWnd` window. My guess would be that Aster is either not creating/registering the `Shell_TrayWnd` window correctly, is not broadcasting the `"TaskbarCreated"` message correctly, or is not handling messages targeting the `Shell_TrayWnd` window correctly. Hard to say since no code has been shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I've added code now.

Comment: @Remy: So the relationship between the `"TaskbarCreated"` and `WM_COPYDATA` messages is purely coincidental. Hence my inquiry to produce a complete question, that does include appropriate reasoning, why the expected result is to be expected. A note on the code as posted: `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` may not return the desired module handle, depending on the particularities of the calling module.

Comment: May be this will help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f4370108-9cf9-4353-a086-a6f5112947ce/taskbarcreated-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

```
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarCreated"), 0, 0);
```

This message is the key. Without this, the Tray WndProc will not get data.